How to get out of a pinned postion
I am writing a book and I have a question about how my smaller female would get out of this position.
She is on her back
Dude is a lot bigger than her and he is on top of her.
He has both her arms pinned at her sides with his knees on them. Is there a way for her to get out of this?
Or do I need to change how he has her pinned?

Yikes. Bad spot to be in for someone who is much smaller. If he is an experienced grappler, you might only be able to rely on a bit of luck and--most importantly--where his hands are. Let's assume he is a guy who has been in fights, but is not trained grappler. Dealing with a trained grappler (BJJ, wrestling, judo, catch wrestling, sambo, etc.) is a separate and much, much longer post.
Disclaimer
Remember this is just my opinion. There are many answers to this question. The key point is to survive. As long as the answer results in survival, I would argue it is a viable answer. That said, let's dig in...
Options
Option 1: The Popup
This will work even if there is a significant size disparity, but be aware that if the attacker is, say, 700lbs, and the defender is 95lbs, that will be problematic. It should also be noted that this works best if the attacker is further up on the defender's body, straddling the stomach, for example. If he is further down and is sitting on the pelvis, that will be a problem and will require either options 2 or 3.
Defender needs to keep her feet on the floor and pull them up as close to her buttocks as possible. Then, in a single, forceful motion, throw your hips up hard, like you were trying to touch your pelvis to the ceiling. When I have taught this, even if you are prepared for it, if the defender pops up hard enough, there is still a chance that you are going to go face-first into the floor above the defenders head. At a minimum he will have to throw both hands out to keep that from happening. His weight is now mostly off of you, and you have shifted his center of balance way up. From there you can scoot out between his legs or possibly even roll him off of you. Stand up and run like hell.
Option 2: Pinning his ankle with your foot
This works better if the attacker is situated further down, like he is sitting on your pelvis. I'm left handed, so I will describe it as I would try to do it; for a right-hander, just reverse the sides. Let's say I am the defender. With my right foot flat on the floor, I will slide it up toward my buttocks until I find the toe of his left foot. I then move my right foot to the outside, bracing the inside heel of my right foot against the outside of his left toe. I then take the heel of my left foot, place it against the inside of his right heel. Then do two things simultaneously in a sudden, explosive movement: 1.) with your left foot, press outward and try to touch the outside of his left ankle to the floor; 2.) try to roll as much as you can onto your right side. Effectively, you are twisting his lower left leg. In MMA terms, you are essentially performing an outside heel hook on his left leg, only you are using your feet instead of your hands. Knee ligaments don't like twisting motions, so slam this on as hard and fast as you can and you can do some real damage.
Option 3: The Butt Scoot
As with #2, I'll describe it as though I am the defender and from a left-handed person's perspective. This technique will work better the further up the attacker is positioned on the defender's body.
This technique requires momentum. I take my left leg and thrust it across my body to my right to get the momentum started. At the same time I push off the ground with my right foot to assist the momentum. Simultaneous to this, I do a hard scoot of my fanny to my left, rolling as far as I can only my right hip. The instant I get any wiggle room for my right hand, I want to jam it against the inside of his left hip (a palm heel to his jewels in the process is never a bad idea) to keep him from shifting his hips back to our left/his right. I continue to scoot my butt to my left and as soon as I have room, I use my right arm and leg to push off of him and escape to my left/his right.
Conclusion
You can combine parts and pieces of these together (for example, adding a popup as part of the butt scoot in #3), so you can mix and match as you see fit. There are any number of other ways you could address this. Personally, I have seen quite a few interesting variations in a number of different martial arts styles. The key thing, I think, is that you will need to be explosive and all of this should be done is an close to a single movement as possible. Once you start taking some of the steps described above, you are tipping your hand to the attacker and letting him know that there is more to you than meets the eye, and he might change his tactics accordingly. Be sudden, be explosive.
I would also encourage you to find a partner to just walk through some of the combinations. There is no substitute for seeing things from the perspective of the defender. You can avoid some missteps in writing your description in your book this way. Best of luck!

Option 1 is easier and more effective the closer they sit to the pelvis, actually. That's why experienced grapplers avoid doing so, it's like a bull ride to mount on the pelvis and much easier to lift and shrimp your way out. IMHO, the best chance is to hook both legs under the arms from behind given they sit close to the chest, then use your whole body (butt and back) to straighten.

I would add a variant to Option 1, so you only lift one side of your hip (doesn't matter which) by pushing one foot off the floor, to lever the attacker off instead of lifting them.

This is so amazing. Thank you! I definitely think knowing her character she will opt for the pinning the ankle. And it'll works cause I have him lower on her pelvis.

Philip Klocking  just to help me visualize  this better she hooks her feet under his arms. Then she using her legs to essentially lift his butt off her and send him backwards?

@BrookeMoloney Depending on the guy's reaction and center of gravity, there are two possible outcomes for this move, both involving a lift of the guy upwards: either she will be able to pull him on his back, which obviously is favourable due to him possibly falling on the back of his head, or she'll have to do a backroll from under him (given he falls to his front), over one of her shoulders. The hooking and straightening is there to make space underneath

Ok. I think I understand.  Thank you again so much
